# Is there a way Azure data studio to find and add local databases under a list automatically?

Tags: ssms, azure-data-studio

When I create a database locally in SSMS it does not show up automatically in ADS. I have to add it as a connection each time.

Generally I use SSMS but am trying to switch away (or just try for fun) from it to ADS.